# How to trigger an event attached to the Shared Event Manager in ZF2?

Tags: events, zend-framework2, eventtrigger, event-listener

An event attached to a (local) event manager

```
public class myClass implements EventManagerAwareInterface {
    ...
    public function __construct(...) {
        ...
        $this->getEventManager()->attach('doEvent', function ($e) {
            $event = $e->getName();
            $params = $e->getParams();
            printf(
                'Handled event "%s", with parameters %s',
                $event,
                json_encode($params)
            );
        });
    }
    ...
    public function getEventManager() {
        if (!$this->eventManager) {
            $this->setEventManager(new EventManager());
        }
        return $this->eventManager;
    }
    public function setEventManager(EventManagerInterface $eventManager) {
        $eventManager->setIdentifiers(array(
            __CLASS__,
            get_class($this),
            'exampleIdentifier',
        ));
        $this->eventManager = $eventManager;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

can be triggered locally as follows:

```
public class myClass {
    ...
    public function doWhatEver(...) {
        $this->getEventManager()->trigger('doEvent', null, ['foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'bat']);
    }
    ...
}
```

If I understand the Shared Event Manager correctly, it's a central register of events and listeners, bundled to `identifiers`. It is known by every (local) event manager. (Btw.: How does this ZF2 magic work?) Every event manager has access 1. to the listeners registered in it and 2. to the shared event manager's "pool". Attaching an event to this pool is similar to the common event attaching to an event manager, but requires an additional parameter -- `identifier` (the key of the "listeners bundle" in the shared "pool"):

```
this->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()->attach('exampleIdentifier', 'doEvent', function ($e) {
    ...
});
```

The triggering from the same class is exactly identical:

```
$this->getEventManager()->trigger('doEvent', null, ['foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'bat']);
```

Now I want to move the trigger-call to another class. But I don't understand, how to pass the correct `identifier`. **How to trigger an event attached to the Shared Event Manager from a class, that has a `ServiceManager` with a different `identifier` / `identifier`s set?**

Answer (score 5):

> How to trigger an event attached to the Shared Event Manager in ZF2?

Despite the name, the SharedEventManager is [*not* an event manager](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/blob/master/src/SharedEventManager.php#L22); therefore it cannot 'trigger' events.

The idea is that you can attach event listener(s) to the shared event manager that would normally be attached to a service (which is event manager aware).

**Why bother?**

The shared event manager provides the following benefits.

- The new event listeners can be attached to event managers that may or may not exist yet
- Allows listeners to be attached to a set of events that may come from different sources, by using 'identifiers'.

The second point is the important one. By using a event manager 'identifier' you are able to attach event listeners to *more than one* event manager/service.

Consider the following

```
use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerAwareTrait;
use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerAwareInterface;

abstract class AbstractService implements EventManagerAwareInterface
{
    use EventManagerAwareTrait;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->getEventManager()->addIdentifiers([
            'my_custom_identifier',
        ]);
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        $this->getEventManager()->trigger(__FUNCTION__, ['foo' => 'bar']);
    }
}

class ServiceA extends AbstractService
{}

class ServiceB extends AbstractService
{}
```

Without the shared event manager if we wanted to attach a listener to the 'doSomething' event we would need to do so for each event manager.

With the shared manager you can target both in one call, without needing to create `serviceA` or `serviceB` or duplicate the event listener.

```
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\BootstrapListenerInterface;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module implements BootstrapListenerInterface
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $application = $event->getApplication();
        $sharedEventManager = $application->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();

        $sharedEventManager->attach(
            'my_custom_identifier',
            'doSomething',
            function($event) {
                // some work
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your  detailed answer. Sure, the `SharedEventManager` is not an event manager, it's just a misleading naming. But is my assumption correct, that it's something like a pool with listeners, accessible for every event manager in the aplication?

Comment: And one more question: Let's continue your example and create a `ServiceC`, that does *not* extend our `AbstractService`. How to trigger the `doSomething` event within a method of the `ServiceC` class? For actually *this* is, what I don't understand, how to do that. (I've just updated/extend my question to make more clear, what it's aiming at.) Or is it impossible and my [logic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794259/how-to-trigger-an-event-attached-to-the-shared-event-manager-in-zf2/30805349#comment49662365_30805349) is wrong?

Comment: I don't think you have explained your issue that clearly; i'm unsure if the SEM is what you need. It's not really a pool of listeners - more of an independent service that allows you to *proxy* event listeners to actual event managers (that match the given identifier). So if you want to trigger an event elsewhere, Service C, you will require a event manager `$em->trigger()` *in* Service C. That event manager could be a brand new one or even an existing one set via `setEventManager`.

Comment: OK, seems so, that I understood the EventManager implementation in ZF2 wrong. (1) There is no common (or *shared*) events/listeners space. Right? (2) The events attached to a SharedEventManager can only be used, if the access to it (over its EventManager) is given. Right?